# Is L = {wxw| x, w ∈ {a,b}*} a Regular Language?

Tags: regular-language, automata

I need to decide whether the language  L = {wxw| x, w ∈ {a,b}* , w≠ε} is regular or not.

I know that L2 = {wxw<sup>R</sup>| x, w ∈ {a,b}*  , w≠ε} is regular, since you can make sure that the word start and ends in the same letter, but it doesn't seem to work without the reversing, (for example w = 10, x = ε)

How do I prove it though?

Comment: Intuitively, it isn't. It's hard to imagine that this language has a finite number of sets of remainders. *Formally*: It's not. You can use pumping lemma. However, you need a stronger version than usually stated (usual formulation can be seen there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). The lemma is also true if applied to sufficiently long substring of the word (if you understand its proof, it should be clear). So, you consider `wxw` with long enough `w`, and apply pumping lemma to the first `w`. With right choice of `w` and `x` you should have a contradiction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because t is not a computer programming question. It is a computer science question but not computer programming.

Comment: related searches leaded me here, I know it is not programming question.
Thanks for the help, I understand the proof now.

Comment: It's important to note that L2 as you've defined it is also not regular. It is, however, context free.

Answer (score 0):

It is not regular. Use Myhill-Nerode. Consider the prefix a^n b. The shortest string ending with b that can be appended to this to get a string in the language is a^n b. This means every such prefix is distinguishable and there's no DFA.